# Is it safe to save Application Context to static variable

Tags: android

I made `Cache` class that use `SharedPreferences`.
It contains below methods.

- `static save(Context context, String key, Mixed value)` (Mixed: String, long, int, double, ...)
- `static load[Type](Context context, String key)` (loadString, loadInt, loadDouble, ...)
- `static exists(Context context, String key)`

These methods contain a `Context` parameter.
Because `Context` is necessary to use `SharedPreferences`.
I think it is very uncomfortable.

So I modify the class like below.

- `private static Context context`
- `static init(Context context)`: save `context` to `static context`
- `static save(String key, Mixed value)`
- `static load[Type](String key)`
- `static exists(String key)`

or

- `private static SharedPreferences sp`
- `static init(Context context)`

  - save `context.getSharedPreferences(...)` to `static sp`
- `static save(String key, Mixed value)`
- `static load[Type](String key)`
- `static exists(String key)`

`init` method will call at `SplashActivity` like `Cache.init(getApplicationContext())`.
(`SplashActivity` is Launcher Activity)

This is a safe way? or is any better way?

Comment: @Thilo then.. is it safe? and are there any other ways?

Comment: @Thilo The asker's approach will fail in ways that the approach in that other thread will not.

Comment: Well, asker... do it as shown in the other thread, not in your splash activity.  I can't explain in detail now that your question has been improperly closed.

Comment: I'm sorry. the question is ambiguous. I'm just worried `context` or `sp` variable can be null or something that can't use, when `SplashActivity` was closed and other `activity` is showing.

Comment: also I will use `synchronized(context or sp)` when use `Cache` class in several thread at same time.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Thank you! It is very helpful! And I apologize my English is bad.